# How to use the Google Cloud Vision API to detect violence or nudity?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

**WHAT I CHECKED:**

I went through the docs: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/

And saw this example: https://github.com/thesandlord/samples/blob/master/cloud-vision-nodejs/index.js

---

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE:**

I would like to analyse every image uploaded by my users before they are saved to my google cloud bucket.

How can I detect violence or nudity using the Cloud Vision API?

Comment: Why didn't you try anything?

Comment: @Nakilon I did try something. Let me add my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of inappropriate content detection via the Google Cloud Vision API. To make use of this feature, just add `SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION` to your API request:

```
 {
    "image": {
          "content": "base64ImageString"
     },
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION"
      },
     // More feature detection types….
    ]
 }
```

You get an response like this:

```
"safeSearchAnnotation" : {
    "spoof" : "VERY_UNLIKELY",
    "medical" : "UNLIKELY",
    "adult" : "VERY_UNLIKELY",
    "violence" : "VERY_UNLIKELY"
 }
```

To read more about this feature, read the [blog article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/08/filtering-inappropriate-content-with-the-cloud-vision-api) by Google.

Comment: And how do I make my API request ? Let me add my current code.

Comment: here is a tutorial on running detections on images via cloud vision in node: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-vision-nodejs/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#8